# Custom keyboard shortcuts to start menu shortcuts work only if some other random item is open first

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been creating and using custom keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl + Alt + ) to open shortcuts to apps and folders for years. They always worked. Recently, however, they only work if an app or window is already open on the desktop. I'm not referring to the app or window that the shortcut points to, but any random app or window. If the desktop is empty, (except for the usual icons, of course), then none of my shortcuts will work. If I open something, like a browser for instance, then all shortcuts work fine, but if I close everything, no shortcuts will work. Has anyone else had this experience? Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It was NVIDIA GeForce Experience which puts it's own Ctrl + Alt + Key(s) shortcut(s) on the desktop.